# Why do tutorials that dockerize Node.js require you to also install Node.js on the host?

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

What's the point of having Node.js and Vue.js installed on my host and then also getting a Node/Vue image for Docker? Every Vue.js tutorial says to install Node and Vue to the host first and then get the Docker image, is this not redundant?

*Examples*:

1. https://morioh.com/p/3021edac7ef1
2. https://jonathanmh.com/deploying-a-vue-js-single-page-app-including-router-with-docker/
3. https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-vue-app/

I'm using a Windows 10 host and was trying to avoid installing Node and Vue to Windows if possible, unless there are particular advantages to doing so, which hopefully someone can enumerate. Otherwise, maybe someone can confirm that it's redundant to also install Node/Vue on the host and state why it's silly and redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, it is redundant but easier. A container is a running instance of an image, an image that was created (probably) using a Dockerfile with the instructions, so how would you go about doing everything from the container?

Would you add the creation of the app to the Dockerfile or would you connect to the container using bash and run the commands from there? If you connect with bash you'll lost everything once you remove the container. Once your app is created inside your container how would you get it out? I mean you need to write your app's code. You could store you data using docker volumes but that gets complicated depending were you are running Docker. For example on Mac a virtual machine is created for Docker, so to find that data you'll need to connect to the virtual machine...

It is just easier to do all of that from your local machine and use docker to host your app.

Comment: I understand that the code for your app (*e.g.*, Hello World: https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/18/dockerizing-a-vue-js-application/ ) can be placed on the host, but why does that require Node or Vue on the host?

Comment: The first command in all your tutorials is `npm install -g @vue/cli`, that is a npm package. So, you need to install node. If you already have your app created and it is contanirized you don't need `node` or `vue` in the host. Just run the app from inside the container and you are good to go.

Comment: I wanted to write the app on the host, but use the docker container for running the app, including for the app's development. I still don't understand why I need node or vue on the host. Can't I use the docker container for running the app, even during development?

Comment: Yes you can. Just wrap your code, put it inside the container and run everything from it.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap my code"? And is there a disadvantage to doing it this way? I'm just wondering why all the tutorials are instructing to install Node/Vue on the host as well?

Comment: It also looks like Python-based projects don't follow the paradigm of installing frameworks to the host first. Here's one example: https://ruddra.com/posts/docker-django-nginx-postgres/ yet Vue projects all seem to install to the host first.